# How to keep my next, prev buttons visible when mouse go over them

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

I have  a div that it contains two images as next and prev btn. these images are `display:none;` and when `mouseover` event happens these imgaes will fade in by jquery `fadeIn()`, and `fadeOut()` when mouseout event happends.
The problem is here , when mouse go over these images(next,Pre) they fade out and fade in again! I want they be visible till mouse leave div
html:

```js
 $("#showBoxDiv").mouseover(function(){
            $(".projNavBtns").fadeIn(1000);
        });
          $("#showBoxDiv").mouseout(function(){
            $(".projNavBtns").fadeOut(1500);
        });
```

```css
 #showBoxDiv{
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 950px;   
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height:550px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -475px;
    top:50% ;
    margin-top: -275px;
    background-color: white;
 }
#nextBtnImg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;  
  margin-top: -16px;
  right: 5px;
 }
 #preBtnImg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;  
  margin-top: -16px;
  left: 5px;
 }
 .projNavBtns{
    display: none;
    z-index: 10000;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<div id="showBoxDiv">
 
        <img src="images/next.png" id="nextBtnImg" class="projNavBtns" alt="next" title="next" />
        <img src="images/pre.png" id="preBtnImg" alt="previous" class="projNavBtns" title="previous" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use mouseenter and mouseleave

```
 $("#showBoxDiv").mouseenter(function(){

            $(".projNavBtns").fadeIn(1000);


        });
          $("#showBoxDiv").mouseleave(function(){

            $(".projNavBtns").fadeOut(1500);


        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4vwp4z15/1/

Answer (score 1):

You might like to try out `.hover()` from the [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) library.

```
var btn = $(".projNavBtns");

$("#showBoxDiv").hover(
     function(){$(btn).fadeIn(1000);}, //handle in
     function(){$(btn).fadeOut(1500);} //handle out
);
```